# Scrapy, Aliexpress returning none for prices

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Everytime I try to run this the price returns as none, why? I'm new to this.

```
import scrapy

class AliSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ali_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.aliexpress.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.aliexpress.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
                'current_price': response.xpath('//*[@id="redesign-flash-deals"]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/div/div[2]/span[1]/text()').get()
            }
```

Comment: Some sites change their html code with javascript on load that scrapy won't access. You can check it with developer tools in chrome and disable javascript to see the result. To extract the data this type of site you need to use selenium or scrpay-splash.https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash

Comment: thank you! I will check it out